# How to return the number that has maximum value of divisor?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to return the number that has maximum value divisor of all the divisors. so, far what I have tried is:

```
def max_divisors(my_list):
#Takes each number in list
n=my_list
for k in n:
    #calculate how many divisors each number has
    i=2
    count=2
    while(i**2 < k):
        if(k%i==0):
            count+=2
        i+=1
    count+=(1 if i**2==k else 0)
    print(k,"has",count, "divisors")
print(max_divisors([100,5, 6]))
```

It is perfectly returning 
`100 has 9 divisors
5 has 2 divisors
6 has 4 divisors.` 
Now I need to get the number of maximum divisor. That is, out of all divisors 9 is maximum and so the number 100 should be printed.How I can do this? Any suggestions please. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define `max_divs` and `max_divs_elem` variables and update them to store element with highest count of dividers, i've putted comments with prefix **NEW LINES** to new lines of code:

```
def max_divisors(my_list):
    #Takes each number in list
    n=my_list

    # NEW LINES: initialise max_divs and max_divs_elem vars 
    max_divs = 0
    max_divs_elem = 0

    for k in n:
        #calculate how many divisors each number has
        i=2
        count=2
        while(i**2 < k):
            if(k%i==0):
                count+=2
            i+=1
        count+=(1 if i**2==k else 0)
        # update  max_divs and max_divs_elem if needed
        if max_divs < count:
            max_divs = count
            max_divs_elem = k
        print(k,"has",count, "divisors")

    # NEW LINES: print values of max_divs, max_divs_elem
    print(max_divs_elem, "has maximal dividers:", max_divs)
print(max_divisors([100,5, 6]))
```

Comment: This isn't very Pythonic.

Comment: @Andriy Ivaneyko Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your function is doing too much. Break it into smaller parts.

Have a separate function to get divisiors:

```
def count_divisors(number):
    i = 2
    count = 2
    while(i ** 2 < k):
        if(k % i == 0):
            count += 2
        i += 1
    count += (1 if i ** 2 == k else 0)
    return count
```

Then your printing and searching can be separate:

```
>>> numbers = [100, 5, 6]
>>> divisors = [count_divisors(number) for number in numbers]

>>> for number, divisor_count in zip(numbers, divisors):
...     print("{} has {} divisors".format(number, divisor_count))
```

You can use the built-in function [**`max`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max) to search for the maximum on some criteria:

```
>>> max(zip(numbers, divisors), key=itemgetter(1))
(100, 9)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for rectifying my program mistake. will follow from now on wards.